# Increasing velocity over time

Tags: python

I'm working on a game where you're trying to run away from projectiles but their speed increases overtime. I came up with this solution:

```
vel += vel*0.01
x_coordinate += vel
```

At first it works fine but after some time it gets really fast and breaks the game. Is there another way that I can increase the speed for a some time and cap it at a certain level?

Comment: This is effectively exponential growth with base `1.01`, obviously it has to go through the roof

Answer (score 1):

You should increase the velocity with a constant rate.

```
vel += 0.01
x_coordinate += vel
```

Or an even better choice if you want to cap the speed at a certain point is to slow the rate at which the speed is increasing.

```
acc = 0.01
vel += acc
x_coordinate += vel
acc *= 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is acceleration:

Velocity is the change in position over time. And acceleration is the change in speed over time.

For a constant speed you can basically add your velocity to your position and you will have a constant speed movement:

Assuming position and velocity are vectors:

```
pos = vector(0, 0)
vel = vector(1, 1)
pos += vel
```

If you have some acceleration the problem is still simple. before you change the position you shall change the velocity by acceleration.

Assuming position and acceleration, speed are vectors:

```
pos = vector(0, 0)
vel = vector(1, 1)
acc  = vector(1, -1)
vel += acc
pos += vel
```

Now you have accelerated motion.

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method